# failure to install R package after upgrade my MacOS to Yosemite

Tags: r, install.packages

I recently upgraded my MacOS to Yosemite and then faced R problems with all kinds of packages.

```
> $ devtools::install_github("dvanclev/GTrendsR")

> Downloading github repo dvanclev/GTrendsR@master
Installing GTrendsR
Installing dependencies for GTrendsR:
googleVis
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

Can someone provide me with a solution to this problem?

Comment: Update R, then do `install.packages('tcltk')` and paste result if failed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are running a version of R that is not compatible with the package you are trying to install. You need to update R for this package to work.

- Make sure that your Mac OS X system is up-to-date by running Software
  Update from the "apple" menu at the top-left of the screen.
- Install R from here:
  http://rweb.quant.ku.edu/cran/bin/macosx/R-3.1.3-mavericks.pkg
- Then in your terminal try to install the package:`devtools::install_github("dvanclev/GTrendsR")`